# 14.04 HP dv7 fan speed wont increase

Tags: 14.04, hp, overheating, fan

My laptop HP Pavilion dv7-7030us wont increase the fan speed. It gets quite hot (up to around 70c) but the fan speed wont increase at all. With windows 7 I never had a overheating problem and also with 13.04 I think. I have lm-sensor installed but I dont think its working right. Also im quite new with linux. I can provide any additional info needed and might have to tell me how to get it from terminal. also when I tried pwmconfig it said that were were no pwm-capable sensor modules installed.